# Tag Names for Enumerated Books

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that we have tags for 1-john and 1st-corinthians. Is there a standard convention we should adopt for consistency's sake? I actually like the names of both those tags based solely on aesthetics. But perhaps there are other criteria that take precedence: search, convention, length?

Answer (score 12):

I would say those tags should be of the form:

[num-bookname](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/num-bookname)

where num is just an arabic numeral (tried to put the # sign in there, but the tag thing won't show it).

So I'd go with [1-john](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-john) and [1-corinthians](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-corinthians).